# Test-utils does not update the DOM after firing triggers in all tests except the first

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

I am trying to check for error messages about filling out fields in HTML/DOM after vuelidate is triggered. Which successfully works after the `click` trigger.
Everything works in tests: mounting, element search, trigger, NextTick, vuelidate - error return. But I can’t update the DOM in the second test (and all subsequent tests in the `describe()`) after the trigger. The first test patiently waits for `await NextTick()` and the validator+vuetify adds classes to the label element. But each test individually works correctly.

Tell me please. Why can't I repeat the identical code in the second same test? Thank you.
P.S. I use a VUE + VUETIFY + JEST.

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import 'babel-polyfill';
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from 'vue-router';
import store from "~/store";
import types from '~/store/types'
import util from '~/util'
import i18n from '~/i18n'
import Client from '~/service/Client'
import Login from '~/views/Login'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import Snotify from 'vue-snotify'
import storage from '~/storage'
import config from '~/config'
import inflection from 'inflection'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.prototype.$storage = storage;
Vue.prototype.$config = config;
Vue.prototype.$inflection = inflection;
Vue.use(Vuelidate);
Vue.use(Snotify);
Vue.use(Client);
Vue.use(util);
Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(Router);

describe("Validate login form", () => {

  const route = {
    path: '/login',
    meta: {
      public: true,
    }
  };

  const r = new Router({
    base: '/',
    mode: 'history', // hash
    linkActiveClass: 'active',
    routes: [route]
  });

  const errors = ['error--text'];

  const factory = (values = {}) => {

    return mount(Login, {
      types,
      r,
      i18n,
      store,
      data () {
        return {
          ...values
        }
      }
    })
  };

  it("first it", async () => {

    const wrapper = factory({ email: "" }); // new instance with data

    wrapper.find(".v-btn--block").trigger("click"); // success firing
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot()

    // expect( wrapper.vm.$v.email.$error ).toBe(true); // ok true

    // DOM updated
    expect ( wrapper.find("label[for='email']").classes() ).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(errors)); // ok true - classes containing error class

  });

  it("second it", async () => {

    const wrapper = factory({ email: "" }); // new instance with data

    wrapper.find(".v-btn--block").trigger("click"); // success firing
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();

    // expect( wrapper.vm.$v.email.$error ).toBe(true); // ok true

    // DOM not updated
    expect ( wrapper.find("label[for='email']").classes() ).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(errors)); // bad false - classes do not containing error class

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cleanup the mounted component for each test. For example using `beforeEach()`:

```
describe("Validate login form", () => {
  // ...
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(Login, {
      types,
      r,
      i18n,
      store,
      data () {
          return {
          ...values
          }
      }
      })
  });
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you. But I tried using this option. I also tried using ```wrapper.destroy()``` at the end of each ```it()``` method. In your version, the DOM does not respond to the trigger at all. The trigger itself works, because the validator does its work and ```wrapper.vm.$v.email.$error``` getting empty field error. But the DOM remains unchanged.
PS In addition, in your version, a single launch of individual ```it()``` to give a negative result in the DOM

Comment: what about setting [attachToDocument](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#attachtodocument) option to `true`?

Comment: Thank you for help. But I used this option in both options (and true. and false. Because i still learning tests), your and my version (about ```wrapper.destroy()``` I remember, I know, I reading the description of this option). But this does not affect the result. In ```beforeEach``` both tests do not work, even individually, regardless of the availability of the option and its state. It is the DOM that ignores both tests and remains unchanged (since both the trigger and the validator work fine).

Comment: ```attachToDocument``` with any value does not affect the DOM. In the version with the factory the same way - the option does not affect the result. But tests only work on their own.
PS I use ```toMatchSnapshot``` only for rendering HTML to a file. I clean the file